# RedirectView.as_view not working at the root

Tags: python, django

In a django 1.8 project, I am attempting to redirect `http://myProject/ads.txt` to an external url `http://a.location.that.has.the.ads.txt.file` and thus serve the ads.txt file without using ftp to simply place the ads.txt in the root.
Given this minimal directory structure:

```
django projects
    myProject
        myapp
            urls.py
            views.py
        someotherapp
        yetanotherapp
        myProject
            settings.py
            urls.py (this is the top urls.py)
            views.py
```

in myProject/myProject/urls.py, (the “top” urls.py) I have as the first entry in the urlpatterns list, the lines:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^ads\.txt', RedirectView.as_view(url='http://a.location.that.has.the.ads.txt.file', permanent=False)),
```

followed by many more pattern matching regex’s.  This does not work and fails with a 404.  What does work is

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^foo/ads\.txt', RedirectView.as_view(url='http://a.location.that.has.the.ads.txt.file', permanent=False)),
```

and then calling `http://myProject/foo/ads.txt`
Unfortunately, ads.txt files must be placed at the site root.  I have tried many different regex’s that test fine in a regex validator, but just don’t work (returns 404).  How do I do this without the extra dir “foo”?  Any thoughts appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try adding a `$` to the end of your pattern... `(r'^ads\.txt$', RedirectView...)`

Comment: I did - to delineate end of string - also did not work

Comment: There isn’t anything in the code you have shown that explains why `r'^ads\.txt` does not work but `r'^foo/ads\.txt` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you cannot redirect with the top level urls.py "routing table" to above the Django project root.  A nginx server level redirect did the trick.